# –mtune=arm920t”: command not found

Tags: shell, quoting

When I run `CC=”${CROSS_COMPILE}gcc –march=armv4t –mtune=arm920t”` I get a `–march=armv4t: command not found` error, when i remove `–march=armv4t` and run:  `CC=”${CROSS_COMPILE}gcc –mtune=arm920t”` i get `–mtune=arm920t”: command not found`

How can I fix this?

PS: I'm running as `root@kevin-M51AC:`

```
echo "$CROSS_COMPILE"
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-
```

Comment: Please [edit your question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/214880/edit) and provide the result of `echo "$CROSS_COMPILE"`

Comment: done and dusted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason your command is not working is that you are using *fancy quotes* instead of normal ones. Change all instances of the double quote character from `”` to a plain `"` and it will work as expected.

This looks like you copied and pasted from a web tutorial. You might want to report this issue back to the author.